# LE connection update command disallowed

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hci, web-bluetooth

I am running the following command in [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) LTE (Bionic Beaver) after connecting to central (Web Bluetooth in Chrome):

`sudo hcitool lecup --handle 24 --min 6 --max 7 --latency 0 --timeout 500`

I am getting the following result:

```
@ RAW Open: hc.. (privileged) version 2.22  {0x0006} [hci0] 2258.085117
< HCI Command: LE Conn.. (0x08|0x0013) plen 14  #412 [hci0] 2258.085174
        Handle: 24
        Min connection interval: 7.50 msec (0x0006)
        Max connection interval: 8.75 msec (0x0007)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 5000 msec (0x01f4)
        Min connection length: 0.625 msec (0x0001)
        Max connection length: 0.625 msec (0x0001)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4       #413 [hci0] 2258.086011
      LE Connection Update (0x08|0x0013) ncmd 2
        Status: Command Disallowed (0x0c)
@ RAW Close: hcitool
```

How come the command is disallowed?

Comment: Did you create the connection from the Ubuntu machine or Chrome?

Comment: Started advertising with bleno but connected using Web Bluetooth

Comment: Re *"LTE"*: Do you mean *"[LTS](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle)"*? That is consistent with a (true) typo. (There is also LE (from [Bluetooth LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy), probably unrelated).)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this command is failing is because you're attempting to do it from the peripheral (slave) instead of the central (master). The connection parameter update can only be set from the central. You can try this out yourself by making a connection from the Ubuntu machine to a remote peripheral and then setting up the connection parameters.

Some devices/stacks allow you to **request** a connection parameter update, but this doesn't seem to be supported on [BlueZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_stack#BlueZ).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I used to set the connection interval using by changing /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_* but those files are no longer available on our new Ubuntu system. Do you know how to adjust those parameters before a connection is made?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware where this is made now.